How to Share Jupyter Notebook?
There have been many articles to share python Notebook but none of them seems satisfactory.
I have seen:-

docker (needs docker to be setup)
venv (doesn't work when i switch os for e.g. windows to linux)
pyenv (needs python to be installed)
make executable file (can't tinker with code after that)
colab (needs an active internet connection and sometimes feels slow compared to vscode)

Is there any other way other than this or Do i need to install all the libraries and python on other system?
Just to confirm i want to share code with others so that they can edit/execute/tinker/copy, whatever they want, with the code.
Thankyou

If both "needs python to be installed" and "can't tinker with code after that" are noGos for you, then I see no way. Either you bring it into a format where no interpreter is required on the target machine OR there is an interpreter present that can deal with changing code

There's also deploying JupyterLite if your computation can run in pure Python or packages that work with WASM. A number of options for deploying are here. Recently, you want to use the Xeus-Python kernel if you want the packages pres-installed and ready for users when you notebook launches in their browser. The only host involved is to serve the static files needed. The computation runs inside the browser of the user with Web Asssembly (WASM).

If you add "!" in front of the Ubuntu command, you can run that command inside your jupyter notebook. In that way, you can share both the code and the environment you are working on.
For example,
!apt-get install [something here]
!pip install [some module]


Please don't suggest outdated approaches that can cause users issues. The magic pip command variation was added in2019 (FIVE YEARS AGO NOW) to insure the install occurs in the environment where the kernel is running that backs the active notebook.  The exclamation point doesn't do that and can lead to issues.  %pip install works on all modern Jupyter, including JupyterLite and Google Colab. See more about the modern %pip install command here. ...

 The second paragraph here goes into more details about why the exclamation point may lead to issues.

I'm just suggesting one way that he can use; which is quite common when you are  trying to set up enviroment temporarily. I admit my solution is a lot old and may cause some issue and your solution is better. But you dont have to be rude about it.

I think if you read it back once you understand all my comments, you'll see in no way is it rude. I'm asking you to change one symbol in the second line of your provided code to bring it in line with current best practices while trying to educate you on what is a bad approach that may cause further issues for others you are supposed to be helping. Using the current way will provide a better experience for you and others while using Jupyter these days. By emphasizing the length this has been available, I am trying to briefly establish this is well supported as better. I could've just edited it.

Share environment and content in temporary MyBinder-served Jupyter with typical Python kernels
I would suggest using a gist or GitHub, or some other repo to share the content and configuration files as Dhanush outlines, and add a launch badge to point MyBinder at it so that users get a temporary session on a remote machine they can work with. (For context, MyBinder-served sessions are what the Jupyter Community employs for offering demonstrations of anything that cannot be handled by JupyterLite presently. The service can be pointed at any public repoistory as well.)  If you set up the configuration files correctly, users will already have the needed packages installed in the session when it starts up. Often this is easiest to make a binder sub-directory and put requirements.txt or environment.yml in there that MyBinder will use, instead of the one in root that details everything. The one in the binder directory should have the package versions unpinned and only add what is necessary to get it running in a fresh session served by the MyBinder service without any configuration file. In otherwords, it should be a short list with the bare minimum and unpinned so that as Python, packages, and Jupyter develop, your repo will work to serve content that builds images and launches for a long time. (For getting started determining what you need, you can point MyBinder.org at an repo that doesn't have a configuration file and upload you notebook and try running them. You can then install things as needed to work out the list you want.)
Keep in mind, and stress this to users, the sessions are ephemeral. Once they are gone, they are gong. There's no persistence with MyBinder. Download anything useful you make for uploading back up to a fresh session for picking back up with work later.
Resources with more detail on MyBinder:

Please see the bottom of my answer here for more about that.
See here.
Lots of details here in my reply to 'Writing Jupyter Notebooks'.

JupyterLite
I mentioned in a comment JupyterLite. Instead of using a remote machine, the virtual machine runs deep in the users browser and so it is faster to initiate and more reliable than MyBinder. The limitation is that things need to work with WebAssembly (even the kernels) and the running deep in your browser context limits access to network abilities and how it accesses local files. Other things currently need adjusted approaches or consideration like the use of input() or sleep().
See more about JupyterLite here in my reply to 'Writing Jupyter Notebooks'. Some things may have changed from what I wrote there. For example, I have better luck using Try Jupyter these days than the JupyterLite examples that launch from the links in the upper right side of the documentation pages. And the Xeus-Python kernel is now the recommended WASM one if you want to have sessions come up that have packages pre-installed.

Upload Jupyter Notebook to GitHub:

Create Repository:

Log in to GitHub → Click the + icon → Select New repository.
Enter a name, set visibility (Public/Private), and click Create repository.


Upload Notebook:

In the repository, click Add file → Upload files.
Drag and drop your .ipynb file or click choose your files → Commit changes.


Add Dependencies (Optional):

To include dependencies, create a requirements.txt or environment.yml:

For requirements.txt: pip freeze > requirements.txt
For environment.yml: conda env export > environment.yml


Upload this file the same way as the notebook.


Share Repository URL:

Share the URL of your repository for others to clone and run the notebook.



Done!
